Are $C^1$ functions Holder Continuous on general subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$
So suppose that $D$ is an open and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some n. Given a $f\in C^k(D,\mathbb{R})$ then we know that that all of the derivatives up to order $k$ exist and they are continuous. If we also ask for $f^{(k)}$ to be Holder continuous (for some exponent $\alpha$) then we have that $f\in C^{\alpha,k}(D,\mathbb{R})$. Now can we say that $f$ itself (and its derivatives up to order k) has to be Holder continuous ? I was thinking about $x\sin(1/x)$ that is continuous and Holder continuous but not differentiable at $0$ (not even Lipschitz). On a closed interval we know that differentiability implies Holder continuity but what about on more general domains (as above assuming that we don't ask for differentiability at the boundary). So my question is:

Given $f\in C^1(D,\mathbb{R})$ does it imply that $f\in C^{\alpha,0}(D,\mathbb{R})$ for some exponent $\alpha$ ?
If not are there any assumptions on $D$ that we make for this hold.

Look at $f(x)=x^{2}$ on $\mathbb R$.

To approach a general characterization, it's useful to examine the standard mean value theorem argument for functions in one variable.

Suppose $I$ is a real interval, and $f$ is a differentiable real-valued function on $I$ whose derivative is bounded: There exists a real $M$ such that $|f'(t)| \leq M$ for all $t$ in $I$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz on $I$ with constant $M$: For all $x$ and $y$ in $I$,
\begin{align*}
|f(y) - f(x)|
&= \biggl|\int_{x}^{y} f'(t)\, dt\biggr| \\
&\leq \biggl|\int_{x}^{y} |f'(t)|\, dt\biggr| \\
&\leq \biggl|\int_{x}^{y} M\, dt\biggr| \\
&\leq M|y - x|.
\end{align*}
(We need the outer absolute value on the second line unless we assume $x < y$.)

If the derivative is not bounded, or if the domain is not an interval, this proof gives no information, and $f$ may or may not be Hölder continuous:

geetha's example in the comments has unbounded derivative and is not Hölder continuous. The related function $f(x) = \sin(x^{2})$ is bounded but not Hölder continuous on $\mathbf{R}$. (N.B.: "Unbounded derivative" is necessary for "not Hölder continuous," but not sufficient. For example, the Hölder continuous function $f(x) = x^{1/2}$ on $(0, 1)$ has unbounded derivative.)
The function $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = x/|x|$ on the punctured line is locally constant (derivative identically $0$), but not Hölder continuous on any set containing a deleted neighborhood of $0$. (N.B.: This example is relevant. Although the punctured line is disconnected, this "jump" phenomenon can happen with connected domains in two or more variables.)

<>
To extend to functions of two or more variables, it is sufficient to ensure conditions under which the preceding MVT argument goes through, and necessary to avoid counterexamples of the preceding types. For example:

If $D$ is convex, the mean value theorem argument along line segments guarantees a $C^{1}$ function with bounded derivative is Lipschitz: If $|Df| \leq M$ in $D$, then for all $x$ and $y$ in $D$ we have
\begin{align*}
|f(y) - f(x)|
&= \biggl|\int_{0}^{1} Df\bigl(x + t(y - x)\bigr) (y - x)\, dt\biggr| \\
&\leq \|y - x\| \int_{0}^{1} \bigl|Df\bigl(x + t(y - x)\bigr)\bigr|\, dt \\
&\leq M\|y - x\|.
\end{align*}

If $D$ is merely star-shaped, smoothness of $f$ and boundedness of all derivatives does not even imply uniform continuity. For example, let $D$ be the plane with the non-positive horizontal axis removed, and define $f$ in $D$ by
$$
f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\phantom{-}0 & 0 \leq x, \\
\phantom{-}e^{-1/x^{2}} & x < 0, 0 < y, \\
-e^{-1/x^{2}} & x < 0, y < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The restriction of $f$ to a vertical line crossing the slit is not uniformly continuous, so $f$ is not Hölder continuous.


